# Use of poetry dynamic version with non-package project for idempotent build

Tags: python, version, python-poetry

I'm using poetry to manage a python project that's not a package (it's a machine learning model). I have a bash `build.sh` script that contains multiple stages (train, test, package, install).

I added `poetry-dynamic-version` in order to add a version to the assets that are created when I run the build script. The problem is it generates the version from the latest git tag and any commits since the last tag, updates the `pyproject.toml` and because this file is tracked it needs to be committed which changes the generated version (i.e. the build script is not idempotent).

How do I use `poetry-dynamic-version` so this doesn't happen, my `pyproject.toml` looks like:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "warpspeed-multiclass-model"
version = "0.5.dev25+0263834"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core", "poetry-dynamic-versioning"]
build-backend = "poetry_dynamic_versioning.backend"

[tool.poetry-dynamic-versioning]
enable = true
vcs = "git"
style = "pep440"
```

In my script

```bash
# Update version
poetry dynamic-versioning

MODEL_VERSION=$(poetry version --short --ansi)
export MODEL_VERSION
```

Previously I used `setuptools-scm` which tracks the version in a separate (untracked) file so this issue didn't occur.